# Potential difference between two points on ground

Tags: voltage

I noticed that when I stick digital multimeter's probes in the ground near my house it shows potential difference about 0.01-0.21 V what looks pretty high. If probes are close it's smaller when farther it's higher. It could look as a "step potential" BUT I made multiple trials in multiple random positions dozens feet away from each other and behavior was the same. If it was step potential indeed it would have been noticeable only in one place that is close to grounded object.

Any explanations?

Comment: You are probably measuring the water content and purity of the dirt between the probes, not the "ground". In order to have a ground, you typically need a very long copper rod embedded in the ground (this rod can be anywhere from 6-12+ feet long).

Comment: Probably yes but still why there is so noticeable potential difference? When I simply put probes in a water in a tub it's about 0.008V. I wonder if I connect a diode bridge to the theese two rods will it give enough power to lit a LED :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a so-called "Stray Voltage" - small voltage that often exist between two grounded objects in separate locations, due to normal current flow in the power system. So it's a kind of "background noise" in the big cities. Please find more details here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stray_voltage

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/247632)

Comment: Noted, thank you. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Appreciate your effort, thank you.